# Windows 10 can't run cmd or PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe

I have a problem with my PC. Recently I was using Hardentools to make my PC more secure. Sadly, I made a mistake and blocked myself from using cmd and PowerShell. Is there a way to reverse it? I really need it now. I will appreciate any help.

OS : Windows 10 Pro

btw: I can't reverse it by simply unselecting the checkbox and running the program again: https://www.ghacks.net/2017/02/24/hardentools-make-windows-more-secure-by-disabling-features/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for
[Hardentools](https://github.com/securitywithoutborders/hardentools)
specified a Restore button, which seems like the solution:

> Selecting "Restore" will start reverting the modifications.

[image]